# Library org.geotools.util is missing org.opengis.util.InternationalString?

Tags: java, geotools, jscience

I see the following exception when running the code below...

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:
> org/opengis/util/InternationalString is not an interface  at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:481)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:442)
> ~[na:na]

```
import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.feature.SchemaException;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
....

    SimpleFeatureType schema = null;
    String srid = "27700";
    try {
        schema = DataUtilities.createType(
                "",
                "Location",
                "locations:Point:srid=" + srid + "," + "id:Integer"
        );
    } catch (SchemaException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new RuntimeException("FUBAR", e);
    }
```

**Why is this interface missing from the repository? And how can I fix this?** https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/library/metadata/src/main/java/org/geotools/util/

I can see that this interface (with the same package) exists within another dependency I use jscience...
[image]

Versions:

> ```
> // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-referencing
> implementation group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-referencing', version: '25-RC'
>
> // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-main
> implementation group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-main', version: '25-RC'
>
> // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jscience/jscience
> implementation group: 'org.jscience', name: 'jscience', version: '4.3.1'
>
>  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-spatial (Contains locationtech jts-core@1.18.1)
> implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version: '5.4.30.Final'
> ```

Comment: At a guess because you haven't imported a referencing implementation (gt-epsg-hsql for example) or you are using an unsupported version of Java (i.e. Not 8 or 11) since gt-main should pull in gt-opengis which contains [InternationalString](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/library/opengis/src/main/java/org/opengis/util/InternationalString.java)

Comment: Oh, and please don't use Datautilities.createType for anything other than toy test cases. It is not a good way to create a schema, use SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder instead

Comment: jscience seems to replace the InternationString interface that otherwise could come from gt-main -> gt-opengis. Removing jscience seems to fix it. Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure JScience shouldn't contain that code

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264592/class-conflict-on-different-dependencies

Comment: It seems to https://javadoc.io/doc/org.jscience/jscience/latest/org/opengis/util/InternationalString.html